# US Visa for Bulgarian citizens (EU, but not Schengen)

Tags: usa, working-visas, bulgarian-citizens

I was wondering how much time it will take me to get a US visa for work for Bulgarian citizen provided that I will be having my UK bachelors completed at the time of employment (Summer '18) and a pre-arranged skilled job in Finance. I have no family in the US, but a family friend with citizenship.

What agency would you recommend to use?

Comment: I don't think an agency is generally recommended or necessary.

Comment: It is one of the requirements by the embassy.

Comment: What type of visa? The company who's going to give you the job should be working on making an H-1B application next April. There are a few other categories like the EB (extraordinary ability).

Comment: Sorry I was confused. I also assumed you had a job lined up in the UK and were asking about a visit visa (B1/B2) but reading @mkennedy's comment I realise you are asking about some work-related visa.